# How to get HttpStatus from Service to Component or get the HttpStatus?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular-components, angular-httpclient

im trying to get the Http Status form a list ofresources names "imagePayments" I got URLs from "imagePayments" but there isn't any uploated image on the server, here in My component class i get data from a Service and this data has information:

The interface:

```
export interface responseMemberObject{
                    infoMember: InfoMember;
                     url_images: UrlImages[];
                     images_payment: UrlImages[];
                    } 
                    
                export interface UrlImages {
                    id: string;
                    name: string;
                    kind: string;
                    url: string;
                }
```

The component class:

```
export class MyComponentClass implements OnInit {

 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
                 
  
idMember:String;
auxiliarPaymentUrl: string;
responseMemberObject: ResponseMemberObject;
auxiliarBoolean: Boolean;

constructor(private http: HttpClient,
 customService: CustomService){

this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
            this.idMember = params.get('idMember');
}
        
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadMember();
    
}
            
        
        
            loadDataMember() {
                    this.customService.getData(this.IdMember).subscribe((res) => {
                        let resStr = JSON.stringify(res);
                        let resJSON = JSON.parse(resStr);
                        this.responseMemberObject = resJSON;
                    this.listDocumentsMember = this.responseMemberObject.url_images;
        
                    
                    this.imagePaymentUrl = this.responseMemberObject.images_payment[0].url; //The image URL 
            


            this.httpclient.get(this.imagePaymentUrl, { observe: 'response' })
                        .subscribe((response) => {
                            let resStr = JSON.stringify(res);
                            let resJSON = JSON.parse(resStr);
                            this.auxiliarUrl = resJSON;
                            console.log('response: ', response.status);
                            if (response.status == 404) {
                                this.bollean = false;
                            } else {
                                this.bollean = true;
                            }
        
                            console.log('Headers: ', response.headers.get('status'));
                        }); */
                });
            }
```

How can I get the HttpStatus or validate thar there is an images stored? I tried many of the examples but there is something that Im missing.

When an images exists I got this

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url:"http://server.doamain/folder/images/idMember/paymentImage/"
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse
```

or if the image is not stored in the server I got this:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "OK", url:"http://server.doamain/folder/images/idMember/paymentImage/"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will catch all errors :

```
 this.httpclient.get(this.imagePaymentUrl, { observe: 'response' })
     .subscribe(response => {},
                errors=>{});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the first error, because you are observing the response and trying to `JSON.parse` (after stringifying it..) on a `HttpResponse`, which the error says, unexpected token, as it is not valid JSON. When you are observing the response, the successful response is inside `body`. You don't need to parse it, Angular http-client takes care of that.

In the second response, you correctly get a 404 error, but you are not handling it correctly, actually you are not handling it at all!

So your code should look like this (when using rxjs 7+)

```ts
this.httpclient.get(this.imagePaymentUrl, { observe: 'response' })
  .subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
      console.log(data.body); // here is the actual response from server
    },
    error: (err) => {
      console.log(err.status);
    }
  });
}
```

As a further suggestion, I would recommend the handling of http-calls to a service, that is usually how we do it.